# In digiKam, how can I compute the total number of photos in my database?

Tags: digital, digikam

I am new in using digiKam, and I just started to import and organize my big collection of photos.
Is there a way to know the total number of pictures in my database?

I have digiKam version 7.4.0, in Linux Mint 20.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use digiKam, so my advice might be wrong, but the [digiKam manual](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/digikam-doc/digikam/digikam.pdf) states in the [section on Database Statistic (p. 108)](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/digikam-doc/digikam/digikam.pdf#page=108):

> digiKam provides a unique tool of maintaining the statistics of your
> collection. It includes count of images, videos (including individual
> count by image format), tags etc.
> ...
> You can view your statistics by going to Help → Database → Statistics. A dialog box like this will appear:
>
> [image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!